# Error publishing feature service in GISserver 10.2

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, error, feature-service, publishing

I installed ArcGIS 10.2 for Server just now. I started to create a map using the ArcMap application of ArcGIS for Desktop.

I created My map with just: 1 shape file + 1 gdb file...

there were not any error when I push the anlyze button(I mean I have checked the enterprise db for my gdb file to be published correctly).

After all, when I want to publish my map as a feature service(I mean a service map with the 'feature access' capability enabled) I encounter an error like this(the feature service definition is created with no errors but just not published and running):

[image: error 001369 when publishing my feature service]

I searched all the web but there where no solution for the error!!!
actually there where no useful log in GP results window as you see below:

[image: GP results window]

Comment: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00vp0000002v001369 says this is a generic failure (i.e. could be caused by many causes - maybe a bad install, permission problem, whatever). Have you asked ESRI for support? If you need more help here, you'll have to provide specific details on everything you did before the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem
the solution is as below:
I wanted to publish the feature service but I did it wrong cause not creating enterprise geodatabase. I just created a simple DB.The coorect process should be as below:

1- Create a simple Database in your DBMS(in my case MS-SQL).

2- Use the "Create Enterprise Geodatabase" tool from Arctoolbox and add it to your simple DB created in first step.

3- add the database as ArcGIS server's managed Database .

4- publish your feature service :)

Good luck